# how can you query current user activity in WP7 background agent?

Tags: windows-phone-7

WP7 mango now supports background agents (with some limitations):  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/danielegan/archive/2011/10/18/background-agents-in-wp7.aspx

How can I inspect the user's current activity?   specifically, here is what i'd like to determine:

- what is the active application
- when was the last user interaction

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't do either. Windows Phone does not support inspecting the users activity or anything else that goes beyond the boundary of a 3rd party application's own domain.

The background agents are limited to the application that created them, and the data related to that (in it's isolated storage).

And this is a good thing, since it means creating mal- and spyware is a lot more difficult. Also, a application like you're attempting to make, would principally be considered spyware.

Comment: though i hope someone answers otherwise, i accept everything you say, except the last few words.  As in your definition a screensaver would  also be "in principle" spyware.

Comment: You do not need to know what the last application, or the last interaction was to make a screensaver! Also, you won't get any other answers, because there is no way to do it. Being ignorant won't change the platforms fundamental structure.

Comment: i am ignorant of the platform (i spent an hour looking for any api's related to this though, and obviously did't find),    i just am stating my dislike at your generalization that wanting usage metrics automatically means spyware.

Comment: Spy(ware) -- Soft(ware) that spies on the user. Collecting metrics are spying, no matter how you put it.

Comment: we could keep going on about this, so i'll just stop here.  

i'll mark your as answer if nobody answer's otherwise in the next day.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Microsoft way of doing this would be to provide developers with an API to modify Lock Screen system settings. This is not possible at the moment, but there is a petition to enable setting the wallpaper from an app here: http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/1720049-provide-a-wallpaper-api-to-enable-in-app-setting-o?ref=title

This combined with the ability to change the screen timeout (not possible yet) would achieve the desired effect.

I take it you are probably after custom screensaver with some other information on it and/or rendered/animated content. This wouldn't make sense. The whole point of the screen saver is to save the screen.

There is no better way to save the screen than to turn it off, which mobile devices handle pretty well.

Comment: sorry if the screen-saver example confuses, but it was just my rebuttal to Claus, for saying that any app that needs to know when the last user interaction occurs would be spyware.

anyway, thanks for the attempt to answer!  +1

Comment: Even if we could modify the lock screen, we wouldn't get access to the user interactions or processes. There's no reason, at all, to make that information available to 3rd party developers.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I get you point and I agree. All I'm saying is that if we had access to lock screen it's the device that handles the inactivity timer and triggers it. No access from the app required.